# Unable to interact with switch when added as subview to UIView and that view as a subview to cell

Tags: iphone

I m adding UIView to cell which has a switch as a subview to it. Now I am not able to interact with the Switch. It does not change to value when I tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the view has the `userInteractionEnabled` property set to YES.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled property is YES but then also its not working

Comment: please check the property for all views (cell, view, switch...)

Comment: yes i have kept userInteractionEnabled for all the components :- 1)for cell contentview 2)for view 3) for switch. still i m not able to interact with the switch. whereas if I directly add switch to cell contentview there is no problem.